# ASCII art in HTML

Tags: html, ascii-art

What could I do to make it print like it looks in the HTML document in the web browser?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ###### #    #   ##   #    # #####  #      ######
        #       #  #   #  #  ##  ## #    # #      #      
        #####    ##   #    # # ## # #    # #      ##### 
        #        ##   ###### #    # #####  #      #      
        #       #  #  #    # #    # #      #      #      
        ###### #    # #    # #    # #      ###### ######
    </body>
</html>
```

Gives:

> # # ## # # ##### # ###### # # # # # ## ## # # # # ##### ## # # # ## # # # #   > ##### # ## ###### # # ##### # # # # # # # # # # # # ###### # # # # # # # ###### ######

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-newlines

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use the `<pre>` tag!  Put it before and after your EXAMPLE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
###### #    #   ##   #    # #####  #      ######
#       #  #   #  #  ##  ## #    # #      #      
#####    ##   #    # # ## # #    # #      ##### 
#        ##   ###### #    # #####  #      #      
#       #  #  #    # #    # #      #      #      
###### #    # #    # #    # #      ###### ######
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although technically you'd probably want <pre># ... #</pre> (without a newline) or to use comments (<!-- -->) to eliminate white space you likely do not want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for art that includes escaping characters (i.e. newline `'\'`). See the kittens found here: https://user.xmission.com/~emailbox/ascii_cats.htm - any way to compensate?

Comment: You will need to escape newlines with '\'. For example do '\\' for a single slash ('\') in art.

Answer (score 16):

HTML is designed to collapse white space by default. In order words, all series of white spaces characters (spaces, tabs, line feeds...) are replaced by a single space on rendering. You can control this behaviour with the [white-space](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/white-space) CSS property:

> The `white-space` CSS property is used to to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled.
>
> **Values**
>
> - `normal` Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled as other whitespace. Breaks lines as necessary to fill line boxes.
> - `pre` Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source.
> - `nowrap` Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.
> - `pre-wrap` Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and as necessary to fill line boxes.
> - `pre-line` Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newlines in the source and as necessary to fill line boxes.

In the case ASCII art you also want to enforce a fixed-width [font-family](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/font-family).

```css
.ascii-art {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="ascii-art">
###### #    #   ##   #    # #####  #      ######
#       #  #   #  #  ##  ## #    # #      #      
#####    ##   #    # # ## # #    # #      ##### 
#        ##   ###### #    # #####  #      #      
#       #  #  #    # #    # #      #      #      
###### #    # #    # #    # #      ###### ######
</div>
```

Comment: Although I'm happy for all the rep my answer has created, Alvaro's answer is possibly even more correct, as these days the way to do it is to define a class like they have.

Comment: @JohnFiala Still, it can be argued that `<pre>` is more semantic than `<div>`. Let's say that both answers provide the full picture ;-)