# ASP Label in repeater displays html tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, newline

I want to display some information in a datalist.
I have no control over the code behind only the aspx file. The following code is used. However if the ToolTipText is multiple lines it will display as a single line on the page. Is there a way to make it display as multiple lines ?

```
<asp:DataList id="ThumbnailListViewData" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <ItemTemplate>
        //othervalues
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToolTipText") %>
    <asp:DropDownList runat=server ID="QtyDropDown" Visible=false onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){return false;}" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

---

The data in the datalist gets the ToolTipText from a field in the backend of our system. Newline characters are not saved. I tried adding 
 but this displays as the html tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render a string in HTML and preserve spaces and newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-newlines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially duplicate of

[Render a string in HTML and preserve spaces and newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-newlines)

Enclose the text to `span` and set white space handling.
Like:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToolTipText") %>
</span>
```

**EDIT**

If you don't have newlines in text an you just need to wrap the text into specified width you have to specify width of the block element - like:

```
<div style="width:40px">
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToolTipText") %>
</div>
```

If your text can contain some long words without spaces like UnBelievableLongWordForNoObviousReason etc. you might want to set wrap policy - like:

```
<div style="width:40px;word-wrap: break-word">
    UnBelievableLongWordForNoObviousReason
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work since the tooltiptext in the datalist does not contain the newline characters