# JavaScript newline from file doesn't show in <p>

Tags: javascript, file, newline, element

In my JavaScript I download a textfile with ajax. This textfile contains multiple word on multiple lines. However when I put the retrieved text in a `<p>` all text is displayed single lined. Via `Alert()` or `console.log` I do get the newlines. How can i get `<p>` or another element to display the newlines? 
My question is pretty basic, so I don't think my code is necessary to upload. If  it is, just ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a string in HTML and preserve spaces and newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-newlines)

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is ignored in HTML by default. It doesn't work like `<br>`.

Anyway you can try with adding following CSS to your `<p>`

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: Thank you. I now get the newlines.