# Line breaks are ignored when render text in html template

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, outlook, mailgun

I am developing a website where a user with an specific role can log in and send an email to a mailing list. I am working with Flask, Python and using Mailgun to deliver the emails. I am using an HTML template and the email text is passed as a parameter from the view function to the send email function. The problem is that the email text is delivered ignoring the line breaks. If the email text is:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

It will be delivered as:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

My view function is:

```
@main.route('/send-email-to-mailinglist', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def send_email_to_mailinglist():
    form = MailToMailingList()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.subject = form.subject.data
        form.email_text = form.email_text.data
        send_email('mailing_list@mydomain.com', 
                    form.subject, 'auth/email/to_mailing_list', 
                    description = "now",
                    sender='info', text = form.email_text)
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    return render_template ('send_email_to_all.html', form=form)
```

My send email function is:

```
def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):  
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    auth = ('api', app.config['MAILGUN_API_KEY'])
    url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(app.config['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']) 
    data = {
        'from': '<{}@{}>'.format(kwargs['sender'],app.config['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']),
        'to': to,
        'subject': subject,    
        'text': render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs),
        'html': render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    }
    response = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
```

And the relevant part of the HTML template is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
..
..
    <p> {{ text }} </p>
..
..
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be that `render_template` is expecting HTML and therefore reduces newlines to spaces, which is the usual behavior for handling newlines and multiple whitespaces in HTML, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space#588386).

For how to work around this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks#9492675). Of course, you could also manually insert `<br />` tags or else use an editor that handles whitespace-to-tag conversions for you, such as [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: Thank you . It works. I used inline `css` so my code was transformed in: `<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> {{ text }} </p>`

Comment: I have done more trials an it doesn't work for `Outlook`

Comment: I was able to make it work for `Outlook`. I use the tag `<pre>`. On this link  [link](http://jkorpela.fi/HTML3.2/5.44.html) it says: _"In principle, a P tag is not allowed within a PRE element,  However, HTML 2.0 specification encourages browsers to accept it, with the remark a P within a PRE element should produce only one line break, not a line break plus a blank line."_. Based on this information I changed my code as follow: `<pre>
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"> {{ text }} </p>
                        </pre>`