# How do I get identically written html?

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml, head

I want to take innerHTML from style and show it in a div demo. But it should be written identically, example
I get:

```
#one {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; }
```

and I need to get;

```
#one{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

So be one below the other, with spaces, as written in notepad ++

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("style").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style id="style">
    #one {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: Do you think this will help you: https://prismjs.com/ ?

Comment: CSS: set `white-space` on #demo to `pre-wrap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a string in HTML and preserve spaces and linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you style the output element (`demo`) with the [CSS `white-space:pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), its content will wrap the way you need.

From MDN:

> **pre-wrap**
>
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```js
function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementById("style").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
#demo {white-space:pre-wrap;} /* does the trick */
```

```html
<head>
<style id="style">
#one{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="one"></div>

<div id="demo"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()" >click</button>
```