# Adding newline in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying add a newline after some text every time a button is pressed. Here is the part of HTML file concerning the question -

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<button type = "button" onclick = "prtText('fname')">SEND</button>

<p id="para"></p>

<script>

var node = document.createElement("P");

function prtText(addr)
{
var x = document.getElementById(addr).value;
var txt = x + '\n'
var textnode = document.createTextNode(txt);

node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("para").appendChild(node);
}

</script>
```

Now, when I run the HTML file, every time I press the button, the text on the input box should get printed with a newline. Like this-

```
ExampleText
ExampleText
```

But it gets printed something like this-
`ExampleText ExampleText`.

I have tried the other method like this - `var txt = x + '<br/>'`, but it prints like this - `ExampleText<br/>ExampleText<br/>` and doesn't print a line break.

What do I do?

Comment: @DNT, the `.appendChild(node);` adds new text just after the previous `child` or in this case the previous text, however if I press the button again the same problem arises.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492675/12734467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Here's a snippet that adds the input value to paragraph (`p#para`) and empties the input element on clicking `button#sendBttn`. The value is wrapped in a `div`, a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), meaning it will always start on a new 'line'. <sup>**1**</sup>

<sup>**1**</sup> You can also end a value string with `<br>`, but in that case you can not use a `innerText`, `createTextNode` or `textContent`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", printValue);

function printValue(evt) {
  // only do stuff when the button was clicked
  if (evt.target.id === "sendBttn") {
    const inputEl = document.querySelector("input#fname");
    const value = inputEl.value.trim();
    // value may be empty
    if (value) {
      // create an block element
      const newLine = document.createElement("div");
      // fill with the value
      newLine.textContent = "Sent: " + value;
      // append it to the existing paragraph
      document.querySelector("#para").appendChild(newLine);
      // reset input value
      inputEl.value = "";
      // focus back to the input field
      inputEl.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

#para div {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<button type="button" id="sendBttn">SEND</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating the code! Just realized using Inline event handlers makes the code really messy and its a good idea to use event listeners! P.S: I'm keeping the CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<button type = "button" onclick = "prtText('fname')">SEND</button>

<p id="para"></p>

<script>

var node = document.createElement("P");

function prtText(addr)
{
var txt = '\n'+ document.getElementById(addr).value ;
document.getElementById("para").innerText+= txt;
}

</script>
```

Here you go. HTML elements have property innerText which allows you to edit contents of element. Beware that it will change inside elements if there are any.

Comment: For some reason, it still gives me `ExampleText ExampleText`, notice the space between the two texts.

Comment: What is the code for element with id 'para'? What tag, what styles are applied?

Comment: @NotMyName i've edited my answer to have running code. It works, problem must be somewhere else for you.

Comment: It works after adding the `+=`, but what does it do?

Comment: @NotMyName "+=" shorthand for adding something (concatenating here). You can write `myVariable = myVariable + 1` or use shorter version `myVariable += 1`. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because new lines are transformed into spaces in HTML. For example:

```html
<p>
  This is a sentence. Sometimes sentences get too big to
  fit inside a single line, so we break the line in two.
</p>
```

In the above example, the text node inside the `<p>` element, has a newline, but the rendered output doesn't break there.

Line breaks in HTML are made using the `<br>` element.

```html
<p>
  This sentence is in the first line.<br>
  This one is in the second.
</p>
```

You could use `document.createElement("br")` and append the element between two text nodes to create two lines, but there's a simpler way, `innerText`.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("demo");

elem.innerText = "First line\nSecond line"
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I read through your answer and modified the code and used `.innerText`, but it still prints `ExampleText ExampleText`

Comment: I think you're missing the += in the `.innerText`