# Angular text with formatting whitespaces

Tags: angular

I have the following text, which is properly saved into database, and served back to browser:

```
Very very



long text
```

But in my angular application I get

```
Very very long text

<td [innerHTML]="client.text"></td> // doesn't work
<td>{{client.text}}</td> // doesn't work


// What I wish to achieve displayed into the browser:
Very very



long text
```

How am I able to achieve the consistency as above? I have a textarea which displays the text properly, however I wish to display it in a div/span/td element. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pre` tag to display the exact way it supposed to be.

As per [HTML Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):

> Text in a `pre` element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed exactly as written in the HTML source code.

Try this:

```
<td><pre>{{client.text}}</pre></td>
```

Also you can do with css as well using [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values)., Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492675/6516699)

> `<td style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ client.text }} </td>`

Comment: I think you got this wrong.
I mean the opposite way - I have a text with whitespaces in it and I want them to be displayed, instead of trimmed.

Comment: Oh gotcha, let me fix it

Comment: Updated, Check once

Comment: Okay, that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Naren.