# JavaScript: How to format JSON to HTML to send email?

Tags: javascript, json, formatting

In my application, any error is catch and sent via email for review. I'm currently adding headers and body to the email to help reproduce errors. It's currently displayed in a single row. I would like to display this row in a formatted way so it's easier to read the email.

I'm currently using `JSON.stringify(myJsonHere, null, 2)` to format my JSON. It does work if I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myJsonHere, null, 2))` to display it, but does not work when I add it to a HTML email like `'<b>Headers:</b> ' JSON.stringify(myJsonHere, null, 2)`.

My goal is to get this format:

```json
{
  data: "test",
  id: 1,
  user: {
    id: 1,
    user: "test"
  }
}
```

Instead of this format:

```json
{data: "test", id: 1, user: {id: 1, user: "test"}}
```

Comment: Please add more information! In addition, could you please provide a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are doing here. Are you trying to embed a `<script>` element in an HTML formatted email? Perhaps a [mcve] would help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({ test: 1, nested: { a: 1} }, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'm going to try this