# How to return a response with a line break using FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

```
@app.get('/status')
def get_func(request: Request):
  output = 'this output should have a line break'
  return output
```

Things I've tried:

- `output = this output should \n have a line break`
- `output = this output should <br /> have a line break`

The text itself is returned and I don't get the line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line break only makes sense if the response is an HTML response (i.e. an HTML page). And a `\n` does not render properly as new lines or line breaks, you have to use `<br>` or an [HTML template](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/?h=html+template#writing-templates) + some [CSS styling to preserve line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9492249/2745495).

FastAPI returns, by default, a [`JSONResponse` type](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=jsonresponse#jsonresponse).

> Takes some data and returns an `application/json` encoded response.
>
> This is the default response used in **FastAPI**, as you read above.

But you can tell it to [use an `HTMLResponse` type using the `response_class` parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=htmlre#html-response):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/status', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def get_func():
    output = 'this output should <br> have a line break'
    return output
```

[image: output using plain string + HTMLResponse]

Or, for better control, use an actual HTML template. FastAPI supports Jinja2 templates, see section on [FastAPI Templates](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#templates).

**proj/templates/output.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This output should have a <br>line break.</p>
    <p>Other stuff: {{ stuff }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**proj/main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get('/status', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def get_func(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("output.html", {"request": request, "stuff": 123})
```

[image: output using HTML template + HTMLResponse]

With HTML templates, you can then use [CSS styling to preserve line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9492249/2745495).

Answer (score 9):

Use **response_class=PlainTextResponse**

```
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse
@app_fastapi.get("/get_log", response_class=PlainTextResponse)
async def get_log():
    return "hello\nbye\n"
```

Comment: i used this for displaying GraphQL schema, and it actually showed (in OpenAPI) not just correctly indented, but also colourized!