# How to detect enters from text and display on html page using html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, textarea

I have below data from backend(django)

```
 "Innovator in Analytical Process & Environmental Instrumentation\r\nT&C:\r\nPayment: 100% advance against PI prior to Dispatch.\r\nPrices: Ex-works Mumbai.\r\nInstl. and Comm. - Inclusive for Mumbai region. For outstation, Travel, Food\r\nand Lodging charges extra.\r\nFreight: In your scope.\r\nGST: Extra @ 18%.\r\nDelivery: 2-3 weeks after receipt of advance payment.\r\nWarranty: 1 Year from the date of installation.\r\nCustomer's scope:\r\n1. All kinds of Civil/Electrical/Plumbing works.\r\n2. Construction or Modification of the Line.\r\n3. Tubing for Sample inlet and outlet with tapping on the line with PU push\r\nconnector.\r\n4. Electrical, LAN and signal cables - Supply and laying.\r\n5. Online or Offline UPS - 1 KVA.\r\n6. SIM/LAN/Wifi/Dongle for connectivity.\r\n7. DM Water and Sulphuric Acid.\r\n8. Mounting of Flow Meter or 3-way valve.\r\n9. Lab Test Reports."
```

Its have enters in the text I wish to show them on frontend in my this code :
my text is getting from {{response.remarks}}

```
<ul class="list list-unstyled mb-0 text-left">
     <li><h6 class="my-1">Message Displayed </h6></li>
     <li>{{response.remarks}}</li>
</ul>
```

But its showing me like this
[image: My data showing like this]

But want them with enters how can I do this

Comment: Maybe a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this inside div:

```
style="white-space: pre-line;"
```