# Thymeleaf intercept '↵' as line break in html template

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

On the backend side, I am getting a text, for e.g:

"first line ↵ second line ↵ third line"

and in the HTML I would like this text to be displayed like

```
first line
second line
third line
```

this is my html code:

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="${myVar}">#</li>
</ul>
```

and I can see al the text in a single line, with the '↵' unicode char omitted. And I have the same behaviour with the th:utext attribute, what would be the solution? Maybe it needs any type of preprocessing on the backend, and send another formatted string to the template?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Thymeleaf problem, it's an HTML problem.  HTML doesn't display newlines.  There any ways to change this with css, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks

Comment: this was also my solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace linebreaks with `<br>` in your text before storing in your database. And `th:utext=${myVar}` in the html element will not escaping your text. Be cautious with that kind of permissiveness to fight XSS attacks against your webapp.

Comment: thanks! this is what I was testing now, but I would like a more safe solution, as it is a user input, and I wouldn't like to allow users to send me html

Comment: I am afraid you will not find a more safe solution if you want|need to preserve the original user input as it is. Usual WYSIWYG editors have some bunch of options to handle a safer way to change user input as safe strings. Html encoding on the fly for special chars could be a way for some things.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was

1. on the backend, replace ↵ with a '\n'
2. use css in the html to process the \n as a new line

   ```
   <span style="white-space: pre-line" th:text="${text}">#</span>
   ```