How to rejoin an array of strings with a line break in JS?
I'm trying to rejoin an array of strings that was initially a large block of text separated by forward slashes:
function formatItemData() {
const lineItems = document.querySelectorAll('.cfw-cart-item-data');

lineItems.forEach((lineItem) => {
    let newLineItem = lineItem.textContent.split(' / ');


    lineItem.textContent = newLineItem.join("/n"); // How do I create a new textContent with the strings joined, but with a line break in place of the "/"?
    
});

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', formatItemData);

I can't figure out how to rejoin the array into a new "textContent" but separated by line breaks. Any input?

The notation for a newline is \n, not /n.

you can do it with a regex

In HTML you use <br> tags to create line breaks. Newlines won't force line breaks unless it's a <pre> element.

BTW, I'd suggest using replace (lineItem.textContent = lineItem.textContent.replace(/ [/] /g, '\n')) rather than split and join.

@ruakh You need to escape the / inside the regexp, you don't need to put it in [].

@Barmar: I find [/] more readable than \/, but if you prefer \/, you're certainly welcome to write it that way instead. (The only downside of [/], IMHO, is that not all languages allow it. But JavaScript certainly does.)

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks

@ruakh I didn't think [] would prevent the / from terminating the regexp literal, but apparently it does.

@ruakh It can be made more readable with replaceAll: lineItem.textContent = lineItem.textContent.replaceAll(' / ', '\n').

@Unmitigated: Oh, awesome! Good to know, thank you! (Compatibility table, for anyone who's interested: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall.)

Using .replace() with Regex:
function formatItemData() {
    const lineItems = document.querySelectorAll('.cfw-cart-item-data');

    lineItems.forEach((lineItem) => {
        // Replace ' / ' with a newline character '\n'
        let newLineItem = lineItem.textContent.replace(/ \/ /g, '\n');

        // Update the textContent with the new line-separated string
        lineItem.textContent = newLineItem;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', formatItemData);


Thank you all. @Tim 's function worked. Thanks again.
